# QGIS Data attribute input values on the same side

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am creating a new layer.
Since I've created it in the SpatiaLite layer, then it was fine. I had all my input values on the same side, where column titles are. Unfortunately, I've made mistake in one column type and used the Refractor fields tool. When I saved my layer as the.GeoJSON file, I see, that some of the output values (type-dependant) are displayed on the opposite side, which is troublesome.

[image]

Is there any option to bring them back to the left side?

Comment: it looks like your types have changed from strings to integers for some fields - I suspect there is no way to force them to be strings in GeoJSON

Comment: You might be able to force them back to the left in the Attributes Form Properties, choosing **Text Edit Widget** instead of the default **Range**. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=forms#attributes-form-properties